# Why browser doesn't get content from cache during recursive refresh after first attempt and why window.location.reload(true) not working in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, browser-cache

I have two doubts:

1. While I am refreshing the page in any browser say Chrome. When I made 15 attempts to refresh. I observed in network tab that Out of these 15 refresh attempts, on some attempts it gets the data from cache while on other attempts directly from server. I don't understand this behaviour? I was expecting it to get data from server for the first time and then from cache on successive try in a given time period.
2. And there is long existing problem that `$wnd.location.reload(true)` doesn't work in chrome? And it still exists? Did someone found out a workaround? I have tested it in Firefox (26.0 and 58.0.2) it works, Safari 11.0.3 it works but Chrome 64.0.3282.167 it doesn't ?

Answer (score 0):

> And there is long existing problem that $wnd.location.reload(true)
>   doesn't work in chrome? And it still exists? Did someone found out a
>   workaround?

I had a similar problem and the workaround I used was to clear the cache before reloading using [Cache.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete)

```
if (!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore) {
// check if browser is chrome

  let id = "your-cache-id";
  // you can find the id by going to 
  // application>storage>cache storage 
  // (minus the page url at the end)
  // in your chrome developer console

  caches.open(id)
    .then(cache => cache.keys()
      .then(keys => {
        for (let key of keys) {
          if (key.url.indexOf('file-to-reload.html') !== -1) {
            cache.delete(key)
              .then(window.location.reload(true))
          }
        }
      }));
} else {
  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: This wont scale with customers, as I wont have their browsers cache id.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary In my case the cache storage was set by a webpack plugin (sw-precache) and it set the same cache id for every instance of the app, regardless of browser. Perhaps look into setting up a precache with something like [sw-precache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sw-precache-webpack-plugin) that is compatible with your tech stack or otherwise redesigning your app logic so that a hard refresh is not necessary?